# Why I get eror when I want to use plt.scatter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I wanted to use the scatter function from matplotlib library on a database but I simply can not.

below is my code and the error:

```
import matplotlib as plt

y = df["price"]

x = df["engine-size"]

plt.scatter(x,y)
```

**error: AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'scatter'**

Comment: [`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You must import matplotlib.pyplot as plt. See here for an example https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-scatter-py

Answer (score 0):

Do your import this way;

> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Then run your code again
This should work

Comment: ooooh, my mistake.
thank you so much.